# How can I compare two MERGEFIELD values?

Tags: ms-word

currently I have this:

{ IF { MERGEFIELD M1} > {MERGEFIELD M2} "Thank you!" "Nope" }

But it does not work. It will only work like this: `{ MERGEFIELD M1} > 3`

**Is it possible to compare two MERGEFIELD values?**

Answer (score 1):

In "Examples of IF fields" http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/examples-of-if-fields-HP005187676.aspx an example is given that  covers exactly what you want:

> Here are some examples of ways to modify the IF field codes by using
>   them in concert with other field codes:
>   - Compare a data field with another data field or bookmark
>   This IF field compares the number in the Rate data field with the number in
>   the Discount data field. If the numbers are equal, the specified text
>   is printed.
>
> { IF { MERGEFIELD Rate } = { MERGEFIELD Discount } "We will offer you
>   a larger discount. " " " }
>
> (If number in the Rate data field does not equal the number in the
>   Discount field, no text is printed.)

I haven't tested it yet, but can it be that there's a minor difference between the contents of the two fields you compare? From which type of source you pull the data? I'm not quite sure if Word treats values as values if the data are not correctly trimmed; think of blank characters at the start or the end of the value - you look at it, but you can't see it. Why not output the data into a test document with "[{MERGEFIELD A1}] [{MERGEFIELD A2}]" so that you can check the trimming?

Comment: The link to the help page appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

You must lock your MERGEFIELDs so they do not get recalculated when IF field is recalculated. MS Word will automatically recalculate MERGEFIELDs to «M1» and «M2» when IF field is recalculated, so, naturally, IF field will not have the right result.
To lock a field, select it and press CTRL + F11. To unlock it, select it and press CTRL + SHIFT + F11. For more info, see [Control how MS Word fields are updated](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-and-format-field-codes-in-word-2007-HA010338798.aspx#BM5).

I believe that MS Word's mail merge will not work on locked merge fields.
As an alternative, you can do [mail merge from .NET](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/articles/c-sharp-vb-net-mail-merge) programmatically and have it working in other nested fields (like IF in your example) and with locked fields.